# What does "Application review begins ..." practically mean in job ads in computer science in USA?

Tags: computer-science, united-states, job-search, faculty-application

As opposed to [Do they really mean "in all areas" and "will continue to be accepted until..." in Computer Science faculty opening ads in the US?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100998/do-they-really-mean-in-all-areas-and-will-continue-to-be-accepted-until-i) , we sometimes even see a softer language without a final deadline in faculty opening announcements:

> Application review begins *Date Y*.

No final deadline ("until...") is given. How long after *Date Y* can one apply in the typical case?

(An aside: Assume that the applicant cannot get this information directly by asking, e.g., due to the absense of contact data, and that the applicants network, including that of the supporting advisors if there are any, does not cover the location.)

This question seeks answers from folks who have participated in search committees, have supervised them, or have received feedback as applicants. If it is the case for you, say so.

Comment: Both your questions boil down to one simple answer : get off your butt and get the application finished and submitted...

Comment: @SolarMike Already done, but there are, perhaps, 50 similar ones to go: either with a past deadline or a slightly different subdiscipline...

Comment: If they are interesting and not ancient then it may be worth applying : if they are "open" but 5 years back then probably not...

Comment: @SolarMike All are from this fall, i.e., the review-begin dates are 1 week till 3 months back.

Answer (score 4):

It means that, shortly after date Y, the committee in charge of reviewing applicants will meet and discuss the applications that have been received up to that point and, if they like some of the candidates, they will be invited for interviews and, depending on how it goes, may get an offer. They committee may revisit the applicant pool at a later date and, if the position is still open, they may consider further applicants. So, in principle, you can apply whenever you want but if you wait until after date Y, you may miss out. Of course, it can happen that all good candidates are late but you shouldn't count on that.

Comment: In short, get your application in by date Y, or it might simply be ignored.  In all the searches I've been involved in with this kind of advertisementI've never seen a case where the committee did go back to look at later applications.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you! Might I perhaps ask you to reveal in how many searches you have participated?

Comment: Thank you! When is "shortly after date Y" in your experience?

Comment: Somewhere between ten and 20 over the last 25 years.  Most in my own department, but several in other departments at my institution.   "Shortly afterward" can mean that the applications received by that date are reviewed and anything that comes in late is held in case the committee decides to go back.

Comment: *... and anything that comes in late is held in case the committee decides to go back.* - which it has never done in your experience, right?